# How to Let Custom Module Refer to Imported Module on Main Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here's my custom module stored in `util.py` that wrapps up 3-steps what I always gone-through to read images when using `tensorflow`

```
#tf_load_image from path 
def load_image(image_path, image_shape, clr_normalize = True ):
    '''returns tensor-array on given image path and image_shape [height, width]'''
    import tensorflow as tf
    image = tf.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    if clr_normalize == True:
        image = tf.image.resize_images(image, image_shape) / 127.5 - 1
    else:
        image = tf.image.resize_images(image, image_shape)
    return image
```

But this is quite inefficient to deal with lots of image load since it generally calls `import tensorflow as tf` everytime I read "single image".

I'd like to let this function to inherit `tf` command from the `main.py`'s tf where the load_image actually imported into.

Like..

```
import tensor flow as tf
from util import load_image

image = load_image("path_string") #where load_image no longer wraps the import tensorflow as tf in itself.
```

Comment: moving the " import tensorflow as tf"  and having it in the import section will allow you to reference.

Comment: That's not related to tensorflow actually. You can simply import tensorflow one time on top of `util.py`, and just `import util` in your main.py.

Comment: importing a module inside a method doesn't makes a lot of sense, you should import all the required modules at the top of your script.

Comment: @MatrixTai I'd only want to import a util not whole of util.py

Comment: Then add a file call `load_image.py`. Or using `if __name__ == "__main__"` to separate the code you dun want to compile when imported as module by other file.

Comment: Importing a module in your function is **not inefficient**, the module is imported **only once**. And this patterns sometimes makes sense -- imagine having some optional dependency in utils module -- you would be able to import the module, just not to use those functions that require additional deps.

Answer (score 1):

> But this is quite inefficient (...) since it generally calls `import tensorflow as tf` everytime I read "single image".

imported modules are cached in `sys.modules` on first import (I mean "the very first time a module is imported in a given process"), subsequent calls will retrieve already imported modules from this cache, so the overhead is way less than you might think. But anyway:

> I'd like to let this function to inherit tf command from the main.py's tf where the load_image actually imported into.

The only way would be to explicitely pass the module to your function, ie:

```
# utils.py

def load_image(tf, ....):
    # code here using `tf`
```

and then

```
# main.py

import tensorflow as tf
from utils import load_image
im = load_image(tf, ...)
```

BUT this is actually totally useless: all you have to do is, in utils.py, to move the import statement out of the function:

```
# utils.py

import tensorflow as tf
def load_image(image_path, image_shape, clr_normalize = True ):
    '''returns tensor-array on given image path and image_shape [height, width]'''
    import tensorflow as tf
    image = tf.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    if clr_normalize:
        image = tf.image.resize_images(image, image_shape) / 127.5 - 1
    else:
        image = tf.image.resize_images(image, image_shape)
    return image
```

FWIW, [it IS officially recommanded to put all your imports at the top of the module](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), before any other definitions (functions, classes, whatever). Importing within a function should only be used as a Q&D last resort fix for circular imports (which are usually a sure sign you have a design issue and should actually be fixed by fixing the design itself).

Answer (score 0):

As @MatrixTai has suggested in the comments, you could make `utils.py` like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def load_image(.........):
    ............
```

and in `main.py`, you could `import util` as you want to.